# I have error while take screenshot on surface

Tags: java, android

I have error while take screenshot on surface. After a lot of pictures, this error is made (it comes with the device), but the application does not stop.

After a lot of pictures, this method is no longer working. Do you have an idea about how to solve problems?

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public static void request(Activity activity, SurfaceView surfaceView, OnScreenShotFinishedListener onScreenShotFinishedListener) {

    // Create a bitmap the size of the scene surfaceView.
    final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // Create a handler thread to offload the processing of the image.
    final HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("PixelCopier" + String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt()));
    handlerThread.start();
    // Make the request to copy.
    PixelCopy.request(surfaceView, bitmap, (copyResult) -> {
        activity.runOnUiThread(() -> onScreenShotFinishedListener.onScreenShotFinished(copyResult, bitmap));
        Log.d("MyData", bitmap.toString());
        handlerThread.quitSafely();
        handlerThread.interrupt();
    }, new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper()));

}
```

```
2019-01-29 18:36:07.361 23730-23768/ge.bunny.giffer E/Parcel: dup() failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 2, error: Too many open files
2019-01-29 18:36:07.361 23730-23768/ge.bunny.giffer W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to get last queued buffer, error = -22
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Please refer to [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I edit the question.

Comment: The crux of your problem is `Too many open files`.  What is PixelCopy doing?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/PixelCopy

Comment: Did you ever find out what the problem was?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the same error when using PixelCopy to grab the contents of a SurfaceView continuously (ie. for video transmission). I saw this effect only on Android 7.0 devices.

I attribute this to a memory leak that was present in Readback.cpp which, if I'm not wrong, is what **PixelCopy** uses internally.

https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/8a29c0ec86a9411a07bb10018c3da69fffc0fe7d#diff-3f79906243073ec92400b65644d330654c8b349e6317259e9639f3a026347d17

This fix was added on September 1st 2016, while Android 7.0 was released August 22nd 2016,